# How to create a normalized version of table 1 in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, database-normalization

Want to convert this

Table 1(not normalized)

```
Id name hobby1 hobby2

1, Bob, fishing, games

2, John, camping, hiking
```

**Into something along the following**

Table 2(normalized)

```
Id name hobby

1, Bob, fishing

1, Bob, games

2, John, camping

2, John, hiking
```

The goal here is to create a new table 2 from table 1 where the fields hobby1 and hobby2 are combined into a single field called hobby via normalization

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a union:

```
select Id, name, hobby1 as hobby
from mytable
union all
select Id, name, hobby2 as hobby
from mytable
```